# Why style.display = "none"; is not working on responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

w3_close() method work perfectly fine on mobile devices but on desktop it's not working.How can i fix this?

```js
function w3_open() {
  console.log('open')
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
}

function w3_close() {
  console.log('close')
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card w3-animate-left" style="width:300px; overflow: hidden;" id="mySidebar">
  <button onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-large">Close &times;</button>
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow: hidden;" id='xx'></iframe>

</div>
<div class="w3-Sand">
  <button class="w3-button w3-Sand w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">☰</button>

</div>
<div class="w3-container">
  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Thankyou for your time

Comment: appears to be working fine for me might need abit more info, what sort of OS and browser are you using?

Comment: yeah it's working fine for me too, using firefox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Originally, the display is set
`.w3-sidebar.w3-collapse { display: block!important; }` in w3.css, so even though you change it to 'block' or 'none', it won't affect on anything.

In addition, you need to use `element.setAttribute('style', 'something')` rather than `element.style.display`.

Below is the code that I have wrote for you.
`
function w3_open() {
console.log('open')
document.getElementById("mySidebar").setAttribute("style", "width:300px; overflow: hidden; display: block !important;");
}

function w3_close() {
console.log('close')
document.getElementById("mySidebar").setAttribute("style", "width:300px; overflow: hidden; display: none !important;");
}
`

Comment: 1) _"even though you change it to 'block' or 'none', it won't affect on anything"_  changing it to `block` clearly works, even for OP. 2) _"you need to use `element.setAttribute`..."_  this is 100% not correct